# After importing virtualmachinemanager module Stop-Job becomes an Alias

Tags: powershell

After I imported the module 'virtualmachinemanager' in Powershell (PS 5.1) the cmdlet Stop-Job becomes an alias of Stop-SCJob. I checked that the cmdlet works before importing. Futhermore I tried to make an custom alias for Stop-Job before importing. But sadly that alias also refers to Stop-SCJob after the import.

I also tried to find something on Google, but no luck yet.

Anyone has seen this behaviour before? And more important how do I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could simply remove the alias: `Remove-Item Alias:\Stop-Job` (with `-ErrorAction Ignore` if you want to handle the case where there's no alias). If you want to refer to the original cmdlet without removing the alias, you can use `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Stop-Job`.

Comment: Just thought of that myself :) Looks like that works. I'll go test it thorough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply remove the alias: `Remove-Item Alias:\Stop-Job` (with `-ErrorAction Ignore` if you want to handle the case where there's no alias). If you want to refer to the original cmdlet without removing the alias, you can use `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Stop-Job`.

Thanks to Jeroen Mostert